# Call sidebar by swiping left

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to call the sidebar by swiping left(or right) on the body? without any button to trigger.
Thanks. I am using semantic-ui's sidebar. It's much nicer if i can make it work with semantic-ui's sidebar. But if that's not possible it's okay. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery for this, just place a div where you want to swipe.

```
$("div").on("swipe",function(){
  $(menu).show();
});
```

You only have to put in the names now :)

You can also do swipe left or right, here is a link to further explenation:
http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/event_swipe.asp

Comment: "div" is the name of the div i'll put, swipe is constant? or is it the name of the sidebar? can i replace $(menu).show(); with $('.sidebar').sidebar('toggle')? or what should i put if i want to call semantic ui's sidebar. thank!

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle example, http://jsfiddle.net/gs4ub6kv/1/ hope it helps :) and yes you can replace the $(#menu).show() with $('.sidebar').sidebar('toggle')